# TinyMCE editor not showing in N2 CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce, n2cms, dinamico

I created a new MVC4 project and added N2 and Dinamico from Nuget. Was working well until I noticed that the tinyMCE editor wasn't showing on text boxes, so I added tinyMCE from Nuget too, and it still wasn't showing.

In the Firebug Console, there are three Javascript errors, so I suspect that the scripts stop running before the tinyMCE initialisation code is reached. The errors are all in generated code at the end of Edit.aspx:

```
TypeError: jQuery("#Frame_Outside_Name_e").n2name is not a function 
TypeError: jQuery(".datePicker").n2datepicker is not a function 
TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

I guess I'm missing a file or two, but I can't work out how to get them.

Comment: at le4ast those javascript error are not related to tinymce

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you upgrade to the latest version of N2 (at http://github.com/n2cms/n2cms) which uses ckeditor rather than tinymce. You can get binaries here: http://bitbucket.org/bherila/n2cms/downloads and install via NuGet: `Install-Package N2CMS.Dinamico -Source [path_to_extracted_archive]`

- Relevant forum thread at N2CMS forums: https://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/435952
- Relevant commits on Github: https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/commits/n2cms-2.5